# Filter records based on multiple columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to filter specific set of records which meets below condition

Any record which has account as 'N/A' and amount as 0 then that record should be filtered.

Here the issue is there are some records having account as 'N/A' but have amount other than 0 and those records shouldn't be filtered out.

Input

```
Id   account   amount
1     ABC        5
1     N/A        0
2     PQR        6
2     N/A        0
3     N/A        8
4     N/A        9
```

Output

```
Id   account   amount
1     ABC        5
2     PQR        6
3     N/A        8
4     N/A        9
```

Can anyone please help on this with correct filter condition?

Comment: Correlated subquery using not exists or simply use set logic and minus one set from the other where the minus contains logic which only returns N/A and 0.

Comment: Please do not significantly edit the question as it invalidates the existing answers. If you have a different problem then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it. It seems like a very basic filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`account = 'N/A' AND amount = 0` will match the rows that you want to filter out. Assuming that neither of the columns contains `NULL` values (your sample data does not) then you can use `NOT (account = 'N/A' AND amount = 0)` to invert that filter to find all the rows you want to keep:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  NOT (account = 'N/A' AND amount = 0);
```

If your columns can have `NULL` values and you want to keep them then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  NOT (account = 'N/A' AND amount = 0)
OR     account IS NULL
OR     amount  IS NULL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, account, amount) AS
  SELECT 1, 'ABC', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'N/A', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'PQR', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'N/A', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'N/A', 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'N/A', 9 FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

| ID | ACCOUNT | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 5 |
| 2 | PQR | 6 |
| 3 | N/A | 8 |
| 4 | N/A | 9 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tqml4N2u)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was going through the data and came across a scenario where  dupliacte id which has account as 'N/A' but has non zero amount value. Since it's a duplicate id i need to filter this record but as per the above filter condition it's not getting filtered out

Comment: Id   account   amount
1     ABC           5
1     N/A            0                                                     1     N/A            7                                             Here, along with the 2nd row I also need to filter the 3rd row as it's a duplicate record for id 1 even though it has non zero value in the amount field.

Comment: @Pranali For that different problem, use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function and filter based on priority [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wzRJNcSG).

Answer (score 0):

One option is - for sample data you posted -

```
SQL> with test (id, account, amount) as
  2    (select 1, 'ABC', 5 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'N/A', 0 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'PQR', 6 from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'N/A', 0 from dual union all
  6     select 3, 'N/A', 8 from dual union all
  7     select 4, 'N/A', 9 from dual
  8    )
```

Query:

```
  9  select *
 10  from test
 11  where account <> 'N/A'
 12     or amount  <> 0;

        ID ACCOUNT      AMOUNT
---------- -------- ----------
         1 ABC               5
         2 PQR               6
         3 N/A               8
         4 N/A               9

SQL>
```